# Help in manipulating a test file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file look like

```
aaa/bbb/ccc.bbb
aaa/bbb/ddd.bbb
aaa/eee/fff.eee
aaa/eee/ggg.eee
```

I would like to skip lines ending similarly (where ending is defined by the extension, e.g. `.bbb` & `.bbb`) and add a string (saved in a shell variable) only after all occurrences. The end result should be printed into a new file.

For example

```
aaa/bbb/ccc.bbb
aaa/bbb/ddd.bbb
STRING TO ENTER
aaa/eee/fff.eee
aaa/eee/ggg.eee
STRING TO ENTER
```

Comment: What defines the line's "ending"? The last 4 characters? A dot and then three characters? A dot and any number of characters? Will the file be sorted? Can any `.bbb` lines appear further down the file?

Comment: Yes, last 4 characters define the ending. A dot and n number of characters(but should match each other). File is not sorted but .bbb line will not appear down. Also I would like to save the changes into a new file

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this:

```bash
awk -v FS='\\.' -e '
    $NF != ext && ext { print "STRING TO ENTER" }
    { print; ext = $NF }
    END { print "STRING TO ENTER" }' file.txt
```

Comment: It's working. I would like to save this changes into a new file instead of printing and also "STRING TO ENTER" is a variable($TEMP)  dynamically changing in a while loop

Comment: @Renjesh please include all relevant information in your question. You might want to take the  [tour] to understand how we're different from traditional forums. Asking a question and then extending it by small details is not how we do things.

Comment: Nice, by the way, +1. You could shorten it to `awk -v a="$a" -F"." '$NF!=l && l{print a;}{l=$NF;}1;END{print a}' file ` if you feel like GNUing it.

Comment: @Tredon Thank you Tredon for your suggestion, but this will still print, i would like to append the inserted value in same file or create a new file with entire content. Also END{print a} is printing the value again which is not required. Please help